# Ember direct access to URL doesn't render, but navigating from homepage works

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an ember application that is breaking if I try to direct access a URL sub route. If I navigate to the homepage and then to a sub route, it loads properly.

The issue that I'm seeing with direct access is the page outputs the HTML to the screen instead of parsing it, loading the JS libraries, and showing the normal content.

I work for a large corporation and can't post the site code, but would appreciate some help with common/likely causes where I can troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you see any console errors? If so, you may want to start there.

Comment: the usual difference is that if you deep-link into a route the routes `model` hook is executed, while if you `{{#link-to}}` with a model that model is used. So if you jump from a list view to an item view you use the already loaded, but if you deep link you need to load a new model with the `model()` hook, and if thats failing you get problems. Also maybe your `ember-data` cache is already populated or something.

Comment: the page html isnt rendering, and the JS isnt loading, so nothing in console.

Comment: Wait, is this happening during development in the ember-cli development server or in production?

Comment: It works fine in development where the dynamic build system is in use. When I build and push it to the UAT server, its having the issue.

Comment: looks like the response headers are not including a content-type header

Comment: are you passing any queryParams by any chance while loading the subRoute, if yes you might want to reconsider to use pathParams instead.

Comment: No query params. The problem is on all sub URLs. No content-type header is being sent by the server, so the html/js isnt being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added a content-type = application/json header on my server side and it wasn't constrained to just API calls. For some reason this was only affecting pages when being directly accessed, and not the home page. I moved the header to only be used on API calls and all is well.